How do I get Banks' confidence goal on the second room for "The Recording" mission on hard mode?
Banks' goal for this mission is to hit 6 enemies with a single spectral skull.  Only 1 intel is within reach on the first turn and none of the nearby positions allows for a skull bounce that would hit 6 targets.
Waiting until the second turn would rely too much on RNG and would risk too much damage to the team.
Is this achievable on the first turn without the big head perk?
Screenshot below for mission starting position information.


I tried, and couldn't find a way to do this on the first turn without the Big Head perk. However, doing it on the second turn is not nearly as risky as it seems. The keys are:

Kill the Chapel Shepherd and the Chapel Riot Priest; both are too dangerous to have around in turn 2.
End with everyone behind the cover at the start of the room.
Do not use Jen's Gale Grenade, as you will need it for turn 2.

The Riot Priest is easy enough; put a Death's Door behind it and Jen can knock it in with Static Blast. How you take out the Shepherd will depend on your perks, but it should be doable.

Here, I've set up the Death's Door and moved everyone into position. Banks will throw a Sedative Cocktail directly at the Shepherd to trigger Zan's Suppressive Fire and apply 2 Unsteady. (Banks takes 3 damage from the Shepherd because her cocktail also hits an Absolver, but the damage is acceptable, or can be moved to the Shepherd with Transference if desired.) Zan then follows up with 3 Bolt Burst for the kill, moving into cover afterwards. Jen uses Static Blast on the Riot Priest, and all 3 take cover to end the turn.

Between turns, two new enemies enter, and the existing Absolvers will reposition. The Trackers seem to stay in place and aim at you. In my testing, the Absolvers always move to these same general positions.

From here, you can move Banks and line up nearly enough targets already:

Now you can use Gale Grenade to move additional enemies into the path as needed. Banks can also stand out in the open for the best Spectral Skull positioning, as nothing should be alive at the end of the turn. If you didn't use Transference in turn 1, it can help bail you out now, should the positioning of the Absolvers make it difficult to kill any Trackers with the Spectral Skull.

